# forming a recursion function C++ programming

Tags: c++, recursion

A student can do the things bellow:

a. Do his homework in 2 days

b. Write a poem in 2 days

c. Go on a trip for 2 days

d. Study for exams for 1 day

e. Play pc games for 1 day

A schedule of n days can be completed by any combination of the activities above. For example 3 possible schedules for 7 days are:

homework, poem, homework, play
poem, study, play, homework, study
trip, trip, trip, study
Find a recursive function T(n) that represents the number of all possible schedules for n days.

I have 2 questions...

firstly i had to write a c++ program for this..

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int Count(int n)
{
if (n < 1) return 0;
if (n == 2 || n == 1) return 1;

return (3*(Count(n-2))) + (2*(Count(n-1)));

}
int main()
{
    cout<<Count(2);
}
```

For input 2 it's giving answer 1.. shouldn't it be 7? `homework ; poem ; trip ; exams,pcgame ; pcgame,exams; pcgame,pcgame; exams,exams`

Secondly, suppose i consider `pcgame, trip and trip,pcgame` as the same combinations. How do i formulate an recursive solution for that?

Comment: `if (n == 2 || n == 1) return 1;` you return `1` on input of `2`  Is it that surprising calling `Count(2)` results in `1` ?

Comment: Oh well. I should have paid attention to what was going on. :|

Comment: A good start would be understanding what programming language you're using. C is not C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Could you please elaborate? I'm using c++

Comment: Yet your question says _"firstly i had to write a c program for this.."_.

Answer (score 0):

When `n = 2` the following `if` condition find a `true` paths,

```
if (n == 2 || n == 1) return 1;
    ^^^^^
```

Hence it returns `1` and terminates the recursion.

Comment: Oops.. I should have paid more attention to what was going on. How do i correct it?

Comment: @user3508140, are you sure input 2 will produce output 5 not 4?

Comment: It's what my understanding of the question tells me. I'm not very sure though.

Comment: You said `homework ; poem ; trip ; exams,pcgame ; pcgame,trip`. But `pcgame,trip` needs 3 days.

Comment: Damn. too many mistakes. i meant pcgame, exams. I'll edit it right away.

Comment: Also you don't mentioned whether any event can occur more than one time, say: `exams,exams; pcgame, pcgame;`

Comment: There is nothing mentioned in the question. I didn't think of that case initially. But yes, that should be a part of the solution. So it takes the count up to 7?

Comment: I think you better study the question first, then post the question fully and add what have you tried.